# How do i run a mysql app with mysql connector installed?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I made an C# app on visual studio, and this application works fine with MySQL Server.

But on other machines, even with the MySQL Connector Net installed, it does not connect to MySQL.

```
string ConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;charset=utf8;";
```

Win7 x86,
Visual Studio 2015,
MySQL Server 6.3.3,
MySQL Connector Net 8.0.29

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRFh1.png)

Please Help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you update the connection string accordingly? Does the user have permissions to connect from hosts other than localhost?

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. My connectionString is constant. Is it possible that the difference in the version of dll files is problematic in MySQL-Server with MySQL-Connector-NET? By the way I did not add reference mysql.data.entity. Is it needed?

Comment: So you have a mysql server on each machine you run the app?

Comment: There is no such thing as "MySQL Server 6.3.3" - after 5.7 it jumped to version 8.

Comment: No. I have mysql server only on my machine but on other machine I don't need to server. I added image to first post.

Comment: I meant mysql workbench 6.3.3.

Comment: When you run the application on a machine other than the one running mysql, you have to update the connection string. `localhost` assumes that the database in on the same machine that the application is running on.

Comment: @M.ShahabTaheri "Localhost" is the current device you are currently on from the point of the application running, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost. When the MySQL server is running somewhere else you have to specify where the MySQL server is running. Also, the server must be accessible from the device running the application.

Comment: Thanks Progman. However, the problem is only from connection string. Did I get it right?

Comment: @M.ShahabTaheri The `server=` part of the connection string must contain the hostname or IP address where the MySQL server is running.

Comment: Thanks dear Progman. What changes should I make in the program that I don't need a server?

Answer (score 0):

Shahab Taheri try to change "uid" to "user=root;password="